# firestore Document not deleting (python)

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

all my other crud operations work fine, this is the code to delete document

```py
try:
  db = firestore.client()
  db.collection('collection_name').document('doc_id').delete()
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```

i thought the problem could be commin from security rules so i tried theses rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write, delete: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 12, 15);
    }
  }
}
```

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write, delete: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write, delete;
    }
  }
}
```

Still the document isnt deleted

Comment: Hi can you try this code instead? 

`col_ref = db.collection('collection_name');
doc = col_ref.document('doc_id').get()

if doc.exists:
    print(f'Document data: {doc.to_dict()}')
    doc.reference.delete()
else:
    print(u'No such document!')`

Let me know what the result is or to check if there's an existing document.

Comment: your  code helped me figured that the document isn't found. even though it exists

Comment: thank you i figured my server isnt really creating the ancestor document im querying 
"This document does not exist, it will not appear in queries or snapshots" i have to figure that

Comment: I'll post an answer regarding what we discussed. I would suggest to post another question to check how you add documents on your firestore database

Answer (score 0):

As we discussed the code that you provide is working fine. And i think this code helps you to narrow down the issue and resolve your concern.

Code:

```
col_ref = db.collection('collection_name'); doc = col_ref.document('doc_id').get()  if doc.exists:     print(f'Document data: {doc.to_dict()}')     doc.reference.delete() else:     print(u'No such document!')
```